# Solaris 8 (TSOL) Fatal Fault at MB.T_ENC

Tags: unexpected-shutdown, solaris

In Trusted Solaris 8 (TSOL) I am receiving the following error on the console:

```
<date> <hostname> rmclomv: SC initiating hard host system shutdown due to fault at MB.T_ENC.
```

Is anyone aware of what exactly MB.T_ENC is and what may be causing this error?

UPDATE: I mixed up servers and originally posted this as Solaris 10 TE.  However, it is TSOL 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is telling you that your system has been shutdown because the temperature in the enclosure got too hot (or possibly that you have a faulty sensor). Check that all your fans are working and not blocked. Have a look in the output of

```
/usr/platform/`uname -m`/sbin/prtdiag -v
```

which gives some information about the temperature sensors and their location.

Comment: Thanks.  From that I get "picl_initialize failed: General system failure".

Comment: Hmm never seen that - try `prtdiag -v` failing that I'm lost.

Comment: I am starting to think ALOM itself may be messing up.

Comment: The picl error sounds like picld isn't running. Check for it with ps, and try starting it manually if not.